# Laravel localization shows unknown characters in Thai

Tags: php, laravel, localization, thai

I am translating all my messages to thai aside from en-us. 
Now I have encountered a problem that an Unknown Question mark character shows up.

The code:

```
{!! trans('messages.client_dashboard') !!}
```

The expected result:

```
แดชบอร์ดลูกค้า
```

The result:

```
���ดชบอร์ดลูกค้า
```

I dont seem to understand why this happens. in my header there is the two

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Any help would help greatly.

Comment: Remove the unwanted space from messages.client_dashboard if any... or else use regular expression before converting it into thai

Comment: There was no space when I checked it

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing some other Thai font on your system.

Comment: In past I had faced similar issue. On one system text was looking fine but on another system had similar issue.

Comment: I guess I found the problem. One of my codes use ucfirst() method.
I just removed it and it now works fine.